# Echoing image tag in PHP using path

Tags: php, echo

```
<?php

$dir= 'C:\xampp\htdocs\img';

echo "<img src='".$dir."\america.jpg' alt='icon'>";

?>
```

I just written this code for test and I couldn't get able to display image on browser.

Comment: What is happen if you try full path `<img src='C:\xampp\htdocs\img\america.jpg' alt='icon'>` is it showing the image?

Comment: Try - `src='/img/america.jpg'`.

Comment: Don't use absolute server paths for `img`-tags. Use relative from the document root (the image needs to be under the document root)..

Comment: @S.I. I don't want to hardcode the path, it is dynamic

Comment: Just wanted to see if is showing the image at all..

Comment: Dynamic means?? The folder name changes every time?

Comment: okey....my main concept is C:\xampp\htdocs\img will remain same after that image name will be variable. for that I am going to use foreach loop.   and I made this code to test whether img tag accepting variable or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you are using is not correct, try this:

```
$path = '/img/';
$imgName = 'america.jpg';
echo '<img src="'. $path.$imgName .'" alt="icon">';
// If img folder is present in the same directory
```

or

```
$path = '../img/';
$imgName = 'america.jpg';
echo '<img src="'. $path.$imgName .'" alt="icon">';
// If img folder is present one directory upwards from current directory
```

Comment: <?php
    $dir= '/img/';
    $file_display = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
    if (file_exists($dir) == false) 
    { echo 'Directory \''. $dir. '\' not found!';
    }
    else 
    {
    $dir_contents = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($dir_contents as $file) 
    {
    $tmp = explode('.', $file);
    $f_e = end($tmp);
    $file_type = strtolower($f_e);
    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && in_array($file_type, $file_display) == true) 
    {
    echo "<img src="',$dir,$file,'" alt="',$file, '" />";
    } }
    }
    ?>

Comment: What is this ??

Comment: unexpected '',$dir,$file,'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'  ------- this error getting me write now

Comment: Manji, plaese use . concat in place of , comma and try again

Comment: nothing happened different :'( got the same error ----expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128128/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-manjiri-parab).

Comment: @ManjiriParab: it isn't clear what that additional code is for. If that is a new question, please ask a separate question, where the code can be formatted in a readable fashion.